# Como habilitar ou desabilitar um input de acordo com opção de um select html por javascript?

Tags: php, javascript, html

Quero que um input inicie desabilitado e quando a pessoa selecionar por exemplo uma determinada opção do select o input fique habilitado.

Comment: Tem como descrever o que já tentou fazer?

Comment: To buscando ajuda.. não sei muito javascript

Comment: Então comece lendo sobre o método `addEventListener` e o evento `change` do seu campo *select*.

Comment: Coloque o que vc já tem de código html/css/js que já ajuda a te responder.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bem você pode tomar como base esse exemplo:

```js
function verifica(value){
 var input = document.getElementById("input");

  if(value == 2){
    input.disabled = false;
  }else if(value == 3){
    input.disabled = true;
  }
};
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <title>Page Title</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <input type="text" name="input" id="input" disabled>
    <br><br>
    <select id="options" onchange="verifica(this.value)">
    <option value="1" selected>1 - Não interfere</option>
    <option value="2">2 - Habilita</option>
    <option value="3">3 - Desabilita</option>
    </select>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 1):

### Selecionando `option` = `Voley` o input será habilitado.

Utilize `getElementById` para identificar cada elemento dentro do formulário.

Para recuperar o valor do option selecionado

```
document.getElementById("jogos").value;
```

De posse desse valor habilite ou desabilite o input.

```js
 function validarForm() { 
       var optionSelect = document.getElementById("jogos").value;

       if(optionSelect =="3" ){ 
           document.getElementById("btn").disabled = false;
       }else{
           document.getElementById("btn").disabled = true;
       }
}
```

```html
    <form method="post" action="https://pt.stackoverflow.com/"> 
    <select name="jogos" id="jogos" onchange="validarForm()">
    <option value=''>Selecione o esporte</option>
    <option value='1'>Futebol</option>
    <option value='2'>Tenis</option>
    <option value='3'>Voley</option>
    </select>
    <input type="text" id="btn" disabled>
    </form>
```